# CMD command with space in path

Tags: c#, vb.net, cmd

I am having an issue with the spaces in my command. I am trying to run the cmd prompt and execute a program that takes command line arguments. I need the cmd window to remain open after the process is finished executing.

I managed to get it working in another section of code, but this time i am almost sure it has to do with the spaces in the path of the argument. If i use a path with no spaces, it works fine. I tried to escape the quotes, but either i am doing it incorrectly, or escaping the quotes do not work.

Basically, I need to make the line below work with spaces and keep the cmd window open after the execution...

```
 Dim ps As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd /k", "C:\common\tools\tap.exe -f flash C:\Users\test project\Desktop\image.signed")
```

I'm know the space between "test" and "project" is the issue, but i haven't been able to get around it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap the path in double-quotes, like this:

```
"C:\common\tools\tap.exe -f flash ""C:\Users\test project\Desktop\image.signed"""
```

Giving you:

```
Dim ps As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start ("cmd /k", "C:\common\tools\tap.exe -f flash ""C:\Users\test project\Desktop\image.signed""")
```